"ERROR: 22001: value too long for type character varying(6)" for polygon shapefile
I am facing an error

ERROR: 22001: value too long for type character varying(6)

while uploading a shapefile to online govt. portal. When I asked the person only mentioned that there is problem with your file no further information. I tried with fixing geometry but doesn't worked.  Anyone have some idea about it?

One of your strings is 7 or more characters long in a field that is only 6 characters long

You can find the rows with select by expression: length( "yourfieldnamehere" )>6
